# Javascript json array to php array

Tags: php, javascript, json

I was trying to use *jQuery UI Nested Sortable 1.2.1* from *http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable* where it prepares a javascript array as

```
ret.push({"id": id, "par_id": pid, "title": title, "depth": depth, "left": left, "right": right});
```

I have tried to send that data through a hidden field as

```
<input id="menuArray" name="menuArray" type="hidden" value="" />    
$('#submit').click(function(){
var ma = $('ol.sortable').nestedSortable('toArray');
$("#menuArray").val(ma);
$('form#target').submit();
});
```

However, when I do

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST['menuArray']);
echo '</pre>';
```

All I get is:

```
<pre>[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] ...</pre>
```

Any solution / tips / hints friends?

Comment: I think there was a function serialize(), which converts the data.

Comment: Very similar to the question posed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually JSON encoding anything anywhere.  You need to use `JSON.stringify` when you set the value of the hidden input:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    var ma = $('ol.sortable').nestedSortable('toArray');
    $("#menuArray").val(JSON.stringify(ma));
    $('form#target').submit();
});
```

Note that JSON.stringify isn't supported by older browsers (like IE 7), you'll have to include [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) for full support.

Comment: Cool Andy. This, in association with `$menuArray = json_decode($_POST['menuArray'],true);` has done the trick ;)